# Is it possible to enable Audit Logging to Cloudwatch in Redshift using Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-cloudformation

I see you can enable logging properties as shown in the documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-redshift-cluster-loggingproperties.html

But it does not specify whether or not you can enable audit logging to Cloudwatch when building a Redshift cluster on Cloudformation. It only specifies properties for an S3 bucket to write to. Is this something that has to be enabled via API/CLI/Console?

Comment: Seems like it's possible on Terraform (since it probably just uses the API) but Cloudformation so far doesn't look like it has the option to send audit logs to Cloudwatch. You can set the log_exports parameter in Terraform to a list of strings of connectionlog, userlog, and useractivitylog to enable all 3 different log types.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/redshift_cluster#logging